# Google Plus Domains Api HTTP Request - circle.insert fails

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

Good morning 
i'm trying to integrate with google+ domains api using HTTP Requests to the service but i'm facing some problems.

i'm using oauth 2.0 to authenticate my connection and my get and delete requests work fine but the post requests always reply bad request.

i've pointed the request to my computer and change to http to catch him here is the catch for a Create circle Post.

```
POST /plus/v1domains/people/106513902856788737684/circles HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX
X-JavaScript-User-Agent: Google APIs Explorer
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 192.168.21.143
Content-Length: 40
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

 {
     "displayName": "My first circle"
 }
```

i'm using the bearer on the heather but not the api key in the url request because it was the only way of get's and deletes work.
Without the API key the get and delete requests works properly but the post requests returns the following response:

```
BadRequest"
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
    }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the request you are making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you are trying to do a [circles.insert API call](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/insert).  If this is correct, you need to ensure that the `displayName` is unique. If another circle with the same name already exists in that user's account, it can trigger the `400-Invalid Value`.

Comment: And what means the same error on Circles: addPeople API Call?

Comment: That that person is already contained in the circle.  Every request should be unique.

Comment: i've already created a circle using the http api now i'm inserting the first person on the new circle, the circle is empty.

Comment: Since this is a new issue, can you post the request you are making and the error in a new question?

Comment: ok i will edit my question to only include the first question and i will insert the new question in a new one

Comment: Done
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724326/google-plus-domains-api-http-request-add-people-fails